# Elastic search regex to get last 7 digits from right

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, pattern-matching, sense

I have data indexed in this format 676767 2343423 2344444 32494444. I need a regular expression to pattern anlayser last 7 digits from right. Ex output: 2494444. Pattern which we have tried [0-9]{7} which is not working.

Comment: Not sure if you can access capture groups, but that seems your only option  - `\[.*([0-9]{7})\]`. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I tried through the sense plugin to create analyser. but backslash is not accepted getting error. This is what i am trying.  POST /telephone
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_email_analyzer": {
          "type":      "pattern",
          "pattern":   "\[.*([0-9]{7})\]", 
          "lowercase": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: If there are no `[` and `]` in your string, you may just try `.*([0-9]{7})`. Or if the Sense plugin does not anchor the pattern use `[0-9]{7}$`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - Tried with .*([0-9]{7}) this pattern and it gets the last 7 digits till space but if i have above 7 digits till space, I am getting no results. Ex : "text": "8765432123 23422334 1234564 899878". Output : {
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": " 899878",
      "start_offset": 27,
      "end_offset": 34,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}     If i add an additional digit to the last number 87878787 then the response is null.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew the pattern is working in online executor but when i try the same in sense plugin its not working for elasticsearch. .*([0-9]{7}). If i add more than 7 digits analyze api returns no tokens.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help more with this. You need help from someone who works with Sense plugin.

Comment: Thanks For the update. Its working !

Comment: Excuse me, what kind of update? What has finally worked?

Comment: we were testing with dummy data once after testing with real time data its working fine

Comment: Aha, so, `.*([0-9]{7})` works. I will post then.

Answer (score 2):

In ElasticSearch, the pattern is [anchored by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators). That means, you cannot rely on *partial* matches, **you need to match the entire string and *capture* the last consecutive 7 digits**.

Use

```
.*([0-9]{7})
```

where

- `.*` - will match any 0+ chars other than newline (as many as possible) and then will backtrack to match...
- `([0-9]{7})` - 7 digits placed into Capture group 1.

The Sense plug-in returns the captured value if a capturing group is defined in the regular expression pattern, so, no additional extraction work (or group accessing work) needs to be done.

Comment: I have another question for you. The above pattern gets the result only if i give data above 7 digits. If i have a value with length below six digits then its not returning. Do we need to change the pattern to get results if the actual value length is below 7 ?

Comment: It seems you will need to insert a space into the pattern after `.*` and then introduce the min argument to the limiting (bound) quantifier: `.* ([0-9]{1,7})`. This will fetch 1 to 7 last digits after a space.

Comment: Ex 1: 123,   Ex 2: 6757677687,   Ex 3: 123 1232.         In this three examples if i use the pattern i need to get outputs as. Ex1:  123, Ex2: 7677687, Ex3:  1231232. Can you please help on this.

Comment: You mean the string has no spaces? Ok, then just use `.*?([0-9]{1,7})`. The `.*?` is lazy and will let 1 to 7 digits in the capturing group.

Comment: It picks the results above seven digits. I need to get only 7 and below. If i have 10 digits then the additional 3 should be ignored. If you look at my previous comment Ex 2: 6757677687 and output is 7677687. Now what i am actually getting is 7677687, 675. I am getting two tokens instead of single token.

Comment: I am not sure how I can help with this since the capture group should contain the value you need, see [how the regex matches and captures](https://regex101.com/r/SHiJjG/1). If the part of the string that does not match (or is not captured) gets into the results, I cannot help here. Perhaps, you are *splitting*, rather than *matching*.

Comment: Do you have any idea on elasticsearch how to get a document with less score in top 25 results ?

Comment: I think it is another question. Feel free to ask after some research. If this answer works for you, please consider accepting.

Comment: we have already reached we haven't got an proper idea so could you please help us